# Как изменить стандартную форму регистрации

Tags: drupal

Не могу найти никак, как изменить стандартную форму регистрации. Помогите, если знает кто. Использую drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

Создаете модуль, в файл mymodule.module вставляете код

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 */
function MYMODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'user_register_form' => array( // id формы
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'user-register-form', //  user-register-form.tpl.php
    ),
  );
}
```

потом создаете файл шаблона user-register-form.tpl.php в папке модуля и там уже выводите форму в нужной вам разметке

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
 function THEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {  
      case 'user_register_form':
        $form['account']['name']['#title'] = "Тайтл поля Логин";
        $form['account']['name']['#description'] = "Описание для поля Логин";
        $form['account']['pass']['#title'] = 'Заголовок поля Пароль';
        $form['account']['pass']['#description'] = 'Описание поля Пароль';
        $form['account']['mail']['#title'] = 'Заголовок поля почты';
        $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = 'Описание поля почты';
        $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'Надпись на кнопке, например Зарегистрироваться'; // t('Register');
      break;
   }

}
```

Comment: а редактировать html код формы обрамления как?
по верстке не подходит стандарт

Comment: Через атрибуты
$form['#attributes']['class'] = array('first_class', 'second_class');

Comment: а дописать div? а дописать текст до/после элемента?
через #prefix и #suffix это будет извращение

Comment: не извращение, скорее просто не красиво ) Для этого есть вариант затемить через https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7. Есть ещё вариант полностью кастомной формы с экшном user/register c name-ами полей соответствующими оригинальным нэймам формы и перед сабмитом дописать <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="user_register_form"> иначе форма не будет работать.

Comment: битая ссыль

Comment: Да, sorry, вот https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7